# Accumulate strings between years using midpoint assumption

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of people-skills and the years they used those skills.  I want to fill those skills between the years where they used them, because I assume they gained them midway between "use".  I'm agnostic to base, tidyverse, or data.table.

My have is:

```
have <- data.frame(
  person = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
  skill = c("S1","S2", "S1,S2","S3","S1,S3","S1,S2" ),
  year = c(2015,2018,2016,2018,2016,2018)
)
```

My want is:

```
want <- data.frame(
  person = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
  skill = c("S1","S1","S1,S2","S1,S2","S1,S2","S1,S2,S3","S1,S2,S3","S1,S3","S1,S2,S3","S1,S2,S3"),
  year = c(2015,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018)
)
```

I can use `fill(.direction = "down")` but I'm not sure how to fill backwards with skills, nor am I seeing a path to deduping when they display multiple skills in a year that they already possessed.

Comment: Why is the desired row 2 *skill* only "S1" and not "S1,S2"?

Comment: Also, should row 8 *skill* be "S1,S3" or "S1,S2"?

Comment: it's quite hard to do anything with your example, because person B and C are identical. There are some examples people give which are very likely to lead to answers which don't generalise, and yours is one of them

Comment: Apologies.  Rows 5 and 6 should have been switched in the 'have' dataset. I've edited it.

The desired row 2 skill is only S1, because I assume they develop the skill midway through the intervening years, as opposed to all the years before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a custom interpolation function to fill in gaps

```
skill_interp <- function(x, y) {
  x <- cumany(x) + 0
  function(z) {
    i <- findInterval(z, y)
    ifelse(i==length(y), x[i], ifelse(z-y[i] == y[i+1]-z, pmax(x[i], x[i+1]),
           ifelse(z-y[i] < y[i+1]-z, x[i], x[i+1])))
  }
}
```

And then use some data transformation to apply those to the grousp

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
have %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(skill, ",") %>% 
  mutate(present=1) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  complete(skill, year, fill=list(present=0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  reframe(, present= skill_interp(present, year)(first(year):last(year)), year=first(year):last(year), .by = c(person, skill)) %>% 
  filter(present==1) %>% 
  summarize(skill=paste(skill, collapse=","), .by=c(person, year))
#    person    skill year
# 1       A       S1 2015
# 2       A       S1 2016
# 3       A    S1,S2 2017
# 4       A    S1,S2 2018
# 5       B    S1,S2 2016
# 6       B S1,S2,S3 2017
# 7       B S1,S2,S3 2018
# 8       C    S1,S3 2016
# 9       C S1,S2,S3 2017
# 10      C S1,S2,S3 2018
```

Comment: @LMc Thanks for catching that. Last minute name change. Fixed.

Comment: could I modify this function to stop accumulating a skill if it wasn't used for some arbitrary X years? I asked the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77255786/interpolate-relevant-strings-between-years-for-arbitrary-x-years/77258392?noredirect=1#comment136202763_77258392), but was unsure if StackOverflow etiquette demands a new question or a comment on the original...

Answer (score 1):

An approach using 2 `unnest`, the first to get the missing years, the second to get each *skill* element. Fulfilling the "halfway through" requirement for *skill*s by using `floor` on half the number of years. Compacting the output with `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

have %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  arrange(person, year) %>% 
  mutate(year = list(seq(first(year), last(year))), 
         first_skill = first(skill)) %>% 
  unnest(year) %>% 
  mutate(skill = strsplit(skill, ",")) %>% 
  unnest(skill) %>% 
  mutate(skill = paste(unique(skill), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  distinct(year, skill, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(skill = if_else(row_number() <= floor(n()/2), first_skill, skill), 
         first_skill = NULL) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   person skill     year
   <chr>  <chr>    <int>
 1 A      S1        2015
 2 A      S1        2016
 3 A      S1,S2     2017
 4 A      S1,S2     2018
 5 B      S1,S2     2016
 6 B      S1,S2,S3  2017
 7 B      S1,S2,S3  2018
 8 C      S1,S3     2016
 9 C      S1,S3,S2  2017
10 C      S1,S3,S2  2018
```

Note: Skip `arrange` if *year* is always ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using purrr and stringr to create a custom function that accumulates unique skill values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

have <- data.frame(
  person = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
  skill = c("S1","S2", "S1,S2","S3","S1,S2","S1,S3" ),
  year = c(2015,2018,2016,2018,2016,2018)
)

have
#>   person skill year
#> 1      A    S1 2015
#> 2      A    S2 2018
#> 3      B S1,S2 2016
#> 4      B    S3 2018
#> 5      C S1,S2 2016
#> 6      C S1,S3 2018

accumulate_strings <- function(x) {
  
  # Split `x` by commas; string to character vector
  str_split(x, ",") |> 
    # Accumulate `x` values and append to character vector
    accumulate(c) |> 
    # Collapse character vector to include only unique values, comma separated
    map_chr(~paste(unique(.x), collapse = ","))
  
}

want <- have |> 
  # Ensure data frame is ordered by person and year so that it accumulates
  #   correctly
  arrange(person, year) |> 
  # Group by person
  group_by(person) |>
  # Add new column called skills to accumulate skills
  mutate(skills = accumulate_strings(skill))

want
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>   person skill  year skills  
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 A      S1     2015 S1      
#> 2 A      S2     2018 S1,S2   
#> 3 B      S1,S2  2016 S1,S2   
#> 4 B      S3     2018 S1,S2,S3
#> 5 C      S1,S2  2016 S1,S2   
#> 6 C      S1,S3  2018 S1,S2,S3
```