# Interpolate relevant strings between years for arbitrary X years

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of people-skills and the year in which they gained those skills.  I have a function to interpolate those skills following a midpoint assumption (excellently answered here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77008576/accumulate-strings-between-years-using-midpoint-assumption").

```
have <- data.frame(
  c("A", "A","A","B","B","C","C"),
  c("S1", "S4", "S2", "S1,S2","S3","S1,S3","S1,S2" ),
  c(2015,2015, 2018,2016,2018,2016,2024)
)
colnames(have) <- c("person", "skill", "year")

skill_interp <- function(x, y) {
  x <- cumany(x) + 0
  function(z) {
    i <- findInterval(z, y)
    ifelse(i==length(y), x[i], ifelse(z-y[i] == y[i+1]-z, pmax(x[i], x[i+1]),
                                      ifelse(z-y[i] < y[i+1]-z, x[i], x[i+1])))
  }
}

have %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(skill, ",") %>% 
  mutate(present=1) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  complete(skill, year, fill=list(present=0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  reframe(, present=skill_interp(present, year)(first(year):last(year)), year=first(year):last(year), .by = c(person, skill)) %>% 
  filter(present==1) %>% 
  summarize(skill=paste(skill, collapse=","), .by=c(person, year))
```

For those persons with long careers, they accumulate many skills, the older of which may be irrelevant (if unused).  I want to "stop interpolating" those irrelevant skills after X years, say in this case 5, so that if I know they don't use it, the skill "drops out" of the resulting accumulation.

My want dataframe is thus:

```
want <- data.frame(
  c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
  c("S1,S4","S1,S4","S1,S2,S4","S1,S2,S4","S1,S2","S1,S2,S3","S1,S2,S3","S1,S3","S1,S3","S1,S3","S1,S3","S1,S2,S3","S1,S2","S1,S2","S1,S2","S1,S2"),
  c(2015,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024)
)
colnames(want) <- c("person", "skills", "year")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, why you want to add skills albeit they haven't gained it. Also where S2 in C:2020 comes from. But this comes close:

```
## helper
ncb <- \(x, ...) paste(sort(unique(el(strsplit(x, ',')))), collapse=',')

aggregate(skill ~ person + year, have, \(x) paste(x, collapse=',')) |>
  transform(skill=ave(skill, person, FUN=\(x) 
                      Reduce(\(...) ncb(paste(..., sep=',')), x, accumulate=TRUE))) |>
  {\(.) .[with(., order(person, year)), ]}() |>
  merge(
    do.call(rbind, by(have, have$person, \(x) expand.grid(
      person=el(x$person),
      year=do.call(seq.int, c(as.list(range(x$year)), 1))
    ))), 
    all=TRUE) |>
  transform(skill=ave(skill, person, FUN=zoo::na.locf))

#    person year    skill
# 1       A 2015    S1,S4
# 2       A 2016    S1,S4
# 3       A 2017    S1,S4
# 4       A 2018 S1,S2,S4
# 5       B 2016    S1,S2
# 6       B 2017    S1,S2
# 7       B 2018 S1,S2,S3
# 8       C 2016    S1,S3
# 9       C 2017    S1,S3
# 10      C 2018    S1,S3
# 11      C 2019    S1,S3
# 12      C 2020    S1,S3
# 13      C 2021    S1,S3
# 14      C 2022    S1,S3
# 15      C 2023    S1,S3
# 16      C 2024 S1,S2,S3
```

First, skills are `accumulate`d using `Reduce`. `order`ed. `merge`d with years sequence by person, finally `NA`s filled by forwarding last value using `zoo::na.locf`.

---

*Data:*

```
have <- structure(list(person = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
    skill = c("S1", "S4", "S2", "S1,S2", "S3", "S1,S3", "S1,S2"
    ), year = c(2015, 2015, 2018, 2016, 2018, 2016, 2024)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I have repeated snapshots of people, so I assume the demonstration of the skill occurs after the gaining of the skill. So, I assume they gain the skill midway between snapshots.  The S2 occurs in 2020 because of this midpoint assumption (like in the skill_interp function).  However, I want those skills to "fade out" if they go unused, which is why C's S3 stops after 2021

Comment: @TorinMcFarland Great, you may want to implement this additional condition as a new variable, then you can include it in the code of my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat convoluted, but this does what I want and is flexible enough. Because my real dataset has millions of observations and very many "skills" though, I needed to run the pivot_longer step piecemeal.

First, I use skill_interp (provided by another user, link above) to interpolate all skills till the end.

```
w <- have %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(skill, ",") %>% 
  mutate(present=1) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  complete(skill, year, fill=list(present=0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  reframe(, present=skill_interp(present, year)(first(year):last(year)), year=first(year):last(year), .by = c(person, skill)) %>% 
  filter(present==1) %>% 
  summarize(skill=paste(skill, collapse=","), .by=c(person, year))
```

Then, I split each skill into their own columns and pivot longer.

```
w_long <- w %>%
  separate_wider_delim(skill, delim = ",",
                       names_sep = "_",
                       names_repair = "unique",
                       too_few = "align_start") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = skill_1:skill_3,
    names_to = NULL,
    values_to = "skill",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )
```

Then, I calculate the last year in which the skill was used, and the year I want to drop it (in this case, 5 years after last use, but this could easily be changed).

```
w_max <- have %>%
  separate_wider_delim(skill, delim = ",",
                       names_sep = "_",
                       names_repair = "unique",
                       too_few = "align_start") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = skill_1:skill_2,
    names_to = NULL,
    values_to = "skill",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>%
  group_by(person, skill) %>%
  mutate(
    maxyear = max(year)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(person, skill, maxyear) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(
    dropyear = maxyear + 5 # can manipulate period of holding here
  )
```

Finally, I calculate my want dataset, filtering out the skills I consider "now irrelevant", and then pivoting wider and uniting.

```
w_long2 <- inner_join(w_long, w_max,
                      by = c("person", "skill"),
                      na_matches = "never") %>%
  filter(year <= (dropyear-0)) %>%
  select(-c("dropyear", "maxyear")) %>%
  group_by(person, year) %>%
  mutate(
    id = row_number()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "id",
    names_prefix = "skill_",
    values_from = skill
  ) %>%
  unite(skills, skill_1:skill_3, sep = ",", remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: any improvements to make this more efficient are quite welcome